# How can I bind from a callback in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, zone

I am trying to bind my template to the value which was returned from subscription via callback. But there is no change detection invoked.

```js
 //authorisation service
public login(data,callbackFromLogin : (msg) => void): void {
    this.http.httpPost(ApiRoutes.LoginRoute,data).subscribe(result => { 
        callbackFromLogin(msg);
    });
 }
 
 //and then in login component 
onSubmit(request) {
    this.authService.login(request,(message) => { 
        alert(NgZone.isInAngularZone());
        if(message) {
            this.ngZone.run( () => { 
                this.message = message;
                alert(NgZone.isInAngularZone());
            });  
         }   
     });
}
```

```html
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

The message does not change, though It gets a value from a service. I guess this issue is related to Zone.

Comment: could you create a stackblitz snippet for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why this not happen.

But some question below.

Who is set `msg` to the callback?

Maybe you want to do `callbackFromLogin(result);` ?

But I think you could try to implement another solution.

Why you are pass a callback to service and not do the function inside the subscription on the component?

Something like this:

```
 // authorisation service
 public login(data) {
  return this.http.httpPost(ApiRoutes.LoginRoute, data);
  // if you want manipulate the message you could use `pipe` method here
 }

 // and then in login component 
 onSubmit(request) {
   this.authService.login().subscribe((message) => {
     if(message){
       this.message = message;
     }   
   });
 }
```

Comment: Sorry , for simplicity reasons , I removed some code from the snippet.
The message is set  after I am getting an error.
 let msg = "....";
callbackFromLogin(msg);
the problem is that I have more logic in a service (in my subscription)
I didn't want to move it to the login component, I wanted to send only the messag (msg)

Comment: You don't need to move the logic to the component, you could use RxJS operators like `map`, `tap`, whatever you need and use them to apply your logic in the service. Then, in the subscribe only update the message in the component. I think this is the best practice.

Comment: Thank you I changed my code..but still I am getting the same result ..the message is passed , but could not be changed in a binding ({{}}) I will post a new snippet now.

Answer (score 0):

I used your advise and change my code to this:

```js
//Service

public login(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.httpPost(ApiRoutes.LoginRoute,data).pipe(map(result=>{
      if (result && result.status == 200) {
      ///
      }else{
        let msg = `my message`;
        return {msg:msg};
      }
    }));
  }
  
  //login component
  onSubmit(request){
    this.authService.login(request).subscribe((result) => {
      if(result.msg){
        this.message = result.msg;
        alert( this.message )
      }   
    });
  }
```

```html
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

Same issue , the message is passed to result ,when I call to alert( this.message ) function , the message is shown above..but there is no change in a template Interpolation however.

Comment: I suppose it could be some issue in my app..because I know such code should trigger the change...
What could be a reason for this strange behavior.

Comment: Where are you getting the httpPost() method from? Angular's HttpClient doesn't have a httpPost() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know.

1. Make a property `loginRequest: Observable<any>;`
2. Inside `onSubmit()`:

`onSubmit(request){
   this.loginRequest = this.authService.login(request);
}`

In your template,

```
<div> 
  {{ (loginRequest | async)?.msg }}
</div>
```

Here's a simple Http call.

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

class SomeService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient){}

  postSomething() {
    return this._http.post('url', toPost);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the httpPost() function from? That's not from Angular HttpClient. Your code might be going out of angular zone in that method.

Comment: Can you post your authService class along with the injections?

Comment: this post goes to NodeJs Api side..using ngZone.run .... didn't help too..

Comment: That doesn't help, Victor. I want to see your dependency Injections in AuthService class. Can you post your AuthService constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes..here is an AuthService:

```js
import { SessionService } from '../session/session.service';
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
import { IUser, UserType } from '../../../../../contracts/IUser';
import { IEmployee } from '../../../../../contracts/IEmployee';
import { Injectable,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {ReplaySubject, Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx'; 
import { ApiService } from '../api/api.service';
import { ActivityService } from '../activity/activity.service';
import { UserActivityAction } from '../../../../../contracts/Library';
import { ApiRoutes } from '../../../../../contracts/ApiRoutes';
import { AlertService} from '../alert/alert.service';
import { MessageService} from '../message/message.service';
import {Events} from '../../../../../contracts/Library';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private userIsLoggedIn : boolean;
  
  constructor(public http: ApiService,private rHttp: Http,
              private session:SessionService,
              @Inject('BASE_URL') public baseUrl: string,
              public router: Router,
              private alertService: AlertService,
              private activity: ActivityService,
              private messageService : MessageService) 
  {
    this.session = session;
  }


 // logIn attempts to log in a user
 handleAuthentication() : void {
    let auth = this.http.httpGetAll(ApiRoutes.AuthRoute);
    
    auth.subscribe(
      data => {
         let results = data.json();
         switch(results.status) { 
          case 401: { 
            this.routeAfterLogin(false);
            this.messageService.sendMessage('',Events.UserLogout);
            break; 
          } 
          case 402: { 
            break; 
          } 
          case 200: { 
            //when success
            break; 
          } 
          default: { 
            this.routeAfterLogin(false);
            break; 
          } 
       } 
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
  
  public login(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.httpPost(ApiRoutes.LoginRoute,data).pipe(map(result=>{
      if (result && result.status == 200) {
     //when success
      }else{ 
        let msg = "some error message";
        this.routeAfterLogin(false);
        return {msg:msg};
      }
    }));
  }

  private routeAfterLogin(state:boolean) {
    this.userIsLoggedIn = state;
    if(this.userIsLoggedIn){
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      console.log("Login");
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      console.log("Failure Login");
    }
  }

  public logout(): void {
    let auth = this.http.httpGetAll(ApiRoutes.LogoutRoute);
    auth.subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("Logout");
        this.messageService.sendMessage('',Events.UserLogout);
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }

 public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
   return this.userIsLoggedIn;
 }

 public fillFileDownloadPass(){
  let getUploadPath$ = this.http.httpGetAll(ApiRoutes.DownloaPathdRout);
    
  getUploadPath$.subscribe(
    data => {
       let results = data.json();
       switch(results.status) { 
        case 200: { 
          this.session.download101AtchFilePath = results.filehDownloadPat;
          this.session.approvedFormsPath       = results.approvedFormsPath;
          break; 
        } 
        case 400: { 
          console.log("didn't find an upload path");
          break; 
        } 
        default: { 
          break; 
        } 
     } 
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
  });
 }
}
```

The handleAuthentication() function is called from the app.component..

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.handleAuthentication();
    this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => { 
      switch (message.type) {
        case Events.UserLogin:
          this.showNav = true;
          break;
        case Events.UserLogout:
          this.showNav = false;
          break;  
        case Events.FirstEntrance :  
         //some message
         break;
      } 
    }); 
 }
```

The ApiService's httpPost function wraps the http:

```js
 httpPost(url:string,data:any):Observable<Response | any> {
      return this._http.post(`${this.baseUrl}${url}`, data )
          .map(this.parseData)
          .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
 }

private parseData(res: Response)  {
    return res.json() || [];
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of abstraction in your code and is quite confusing. In the constructor, the http property is ApiService's instance and rHttp is the old Angular Http. I'm gonna edit my answer with any easy and straightforward way to do http calls using Angular's HttpClient and hope that helps you out.

Comment: I removed the ApiService and now using the http from '@angular/http' , for this post method ..didn't help..unfortunately.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console? And don't use @angular/http. That has been replaced by HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'

Comment: No ,there is no any errors. About HttpClient  , I know but thanks.

Comment: I don't see any code that would go out of angular's zone. If you initialize the message property in the constructor, are you able to see the message in the UI? There might be a disconnect between UI and the component class.

Comment: I found that  this.router.navigate(['/login']) in AuthService , (in login() function, which returns an Observable) caused to this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a Zone related issue as you suggested..in that case:

```js
 onSubmit(request){
    this.message="outer message"
    this.loginRequest = this.authService.login(request);
    this.loginRequest.subscribe((result) => {
      if(result.msg){
        this.message ="inner message"
       // alert(this.message)
      }   
    });
  }
```

When onSubmit() fires , I see the "outer message" binding , but after entrance to subscription it disappears and the "inner message" is not shown at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
In my AuthService, in login() function, which returns an Observable, I am making a call for a this.routeAfterLogin(false) . This function redirects my route to login page in case the error occurs. That redirection inside an observable messes the change detection.
Actually I don't need it ,after removing it everything started to work fine.
Thanks all for the help.

```js
 public login(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.rHttp.post(ApiRoutes.LoginRoute,data).pipe(map(result=>{ 
      if(...){
      // not relevant
      }else{ 
        let msg = "error message";
        this.alertService.error(msg);
        **this.routeAfterLogin(false);**
        this.messageService.sendMessage('',Events.UserLogout);
        return {msg:msg};
      }
    }));
}

**private routeAfterLogin(state:boolean)** {
  this.userIsLoggedIn = state;
  if(this.userIsLoggedIn){
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    console.log("Login");
  } else {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    console.log("Failure Login");
  }
}
```